# Высота блока по высоте изображения

Tags: css

В блоке есть картинка и текст.
Текст должен обтекать картинку. Если текста немного, то высота внешнего блока должна равняться высоте изображения.

Как сделать на чистом CSS, чтобы высота внешнего блока равнялась высоте изображения?

Подгон высоты Javascript'ом работает только с таймером. Около, 50 мс (время загрузки изображения).

[image: Пример верстки]
**Стили**:

```
.wrap {
    background-color: #f76;
    height: auto;
}
.image-container {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
.image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Работает, если внешнему блоку задать `display: inline-block`
Правда, есть одно "но" - для него перестают работать `float: none` и `clear: both`, т.е. перенос строки в HTML приходится делать вручную

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
<style>
.leftimg {
  float:left; /* Выравнивание по левому краю */
  margin: 7px 7px 7px 0; /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}
.rightimg  {
  float: right; /* Выравнивание по правому краю  */ 
  margin: 7px 0 7px 7px; /* Отступы вокруг картинки */
}
</style>
```

Comment: No effect, к сожалению

Comment: @Maxick попробуй так http://i.imgur.com/6tgiYSS.png
вот результат http://output.jsbin.com/kuseduve/1

Comment: Не то пальто. Если попробовать (в Вашем примере) в div "up" оставить пару строчек из всего текста, высота блока уменьшается до высоты текста в нем ("up") и нижний блок "налезает" на верхний.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrap:after {
  display: block;
  content: '.';
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Кстати, можно в качестве контента использовать пробел (точка отобразится). Однако, применим только если у ".wrap" нет соседей слева или справа.

Comment: @Maxick, причём тут соседи справа и слева, если речь идёт об элементах с `float` внутри блока `.wrap`? Точка не отобразится, т. к. высота 0px и `overflow:hidden;`. Так исторически сложилось с тех времён, когда старые браузеры не умели одиночный пробел в `content`